# The name 'GridLengthHelper' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm reading Metro Revealed: [Building Windows 8 Apps with XAML and C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430244917). The book contains this snippet of code which I'm not able to compile:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

...

private void HandleViewStateChange(ApplicationViewState viewState) {
    if (viewState == ApplicationViewState.Snapped) {
        GridLayout.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width
            = GridLengthHelper.FromPixels(0);
    } else {
        GridLayout.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width
            = GridLengthHelper.FromValueAndType(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}
```

The problem is with `GridLengthHelper` class which is not visible for Visual Studio (tried in both VS 2012 Express for Windows 8 RC and VS 2012 Ultimate RC). The build error is:

> The name 'GridLengthHelper' does not exist in the current context

or

> 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLengthHelper' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The Object Browser doesn't show this class in `Windows.winmd` where it should be [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.gridlengthhelper.aspx). What is even more frustrating when I navigate to the path displayed in the Object Browswer:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd
```

and open the `Windows.winmd` file in Reflector, I see that the public `GridLengthHelper` class is present!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use new GridLength(pixels) or new GridLength(starWidth, GridUnitType.Star)